# Spring Boot Composite Key In Docker, Querydsl

Tags: spring-boot, docker, querydsl

i'm using Querydsl, JPA Spring Boot Skill set

and make Select Query at Querydsl, this Query is contain Select CompsiteKey logic,

and my code is working at local IDE, but When i deploy this code by Docker, ECS
then code is not working API is always response EmptyValue

however i convert this query Querydsl to JPA Native Query,
it's working for me.

when i in person build jar in terminal, Likewise it's working for me

Querydsl, CompositeKey, Is there a issue I don't know?

i did upgrade docker container spec

Comment: Without specific code, logs or error messages, it's hard to give a precise answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.